# Swapping between panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am learning Java creating small projects for fun. I am fairly new to it and easily stuck, hence the question I am asking.

I'm trying to create a simple Shopping Cart program, which in it's main panel has a 3x3 grid consisting of empty labels later
going to be replaced with images. And to the right of the grid there is four buttons, Add a Meal, Add a Drink, Total Price 
and Clear All. So when either of the first two buttons are clicked, I want it to change the current panel to the panels corresponding to the button that was clicked. 
The panel that is displayed then has data, like type of the food in a combobox which displays set food and quantity of the food. 
Which then when the user chooses the type and quantity, presses the Add button, that would then change the panel 
back to the main panel and the first empty label now has an image of the item that has been added to the cart.

This is all I currently know and as far as I can get.

Main class

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        JFrame app = new JFrame("Cart");

        MainPanel main = new MainPanel();
        app.add(main);

        app.pack();
        app.setResizable(false);
        app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ShoppingCart();
    }
}
```

MainPanel class

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private final JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[9]; 
    private final JButton button[] = new JButton[4]; 

    public MainPanel()
    {
        String buttonText[] ={"Add a Meal", "Add a Drink", "Total Price", "Clear All"};
        String buttonToolTipText[] =
        {"This will add food", "This will add drink", "This will display the price", "Clear the cart"};

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 2, 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton(buttonText[i]);
            button[i].setOpaque(true);
            button[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            button[i].setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            button[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
            button[i].setVisible(true);
            button[i].setToolTipText(buttonToolTipText[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
            buttonPanel.add(button[i]);
        }

        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new JLabel();
            labels[i].setOpaque(true);
            labels[i].setVisible(true);
            labels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            labels[i].setBorder(border);
            labels[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            labelPanel.add(labels[i]);
            //set empty label to the image of the type chose, 
            //if right clicked, show type and quantity chosen
        }
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(button[0] == e.getSource())
        {
            //Change panel to Meal panel
        }
        if(button[1] == e.getSource())
        {
            //Change panel to Drink panel
        }
        if(button[2] == e.getSource())
        {
            //JOptionPane to show total price
        }
        if(button[3] == e.getSource())
        {
            //Check whether labels are empty, if not clear them else display message
        }
    }
}
```

MealPanel class

```
public class MealPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public MealPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 3, 3));
        JPanel inputField = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 3, 3));
        JPanel addCancel = new JPanel();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Add a Meal");
        title.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5,0,10,0, new Color(0,0,0,0)));
        titlePanel.add(title);

        JLabel type = new JLabel("Type:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        labelPanel.add(type);
        JLabel quantity = new JLabel("Quantity:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        labelPanel.add(quantity);

        final String arr[] = {"Burger", "Pizza"};
        JComboBox mealType = new JComboBox(arr);
        inputField.add(mealType);
        JTextField quant = new JTextField();
        inputField.add(quant);

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(this);
        addCancel.add(add);
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(this);
        addCancel.add(cancel);

        add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(inputField, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(addCancel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       //If cancel is pressed, return back to main, nothing changed on this panel
       //else if add is pressed, set the type and quantity and return back to main
    }
}
```

I guess what is shown, is I don't know how to specifically change the current panel to the panel chosen via which button is clicked. Then when the panel is shown, how to set the data then change the panel back to the MainPanel to then have that type of food displayed in the label as an image within the grid corresponding to the type that was chosen, so either a burger or pizza in the first empty label.

How would one go about doing the application?

Comment: Have you attempt any `add()` and `remove()` methods for the other Panels in the main panel?

Comment: I have not as I said I'm not sure what I am supposed to do next once I got to the code that I have posted.

Comment: Any answer that doesn’t use `CardLayout` is a waste of time

Comment: If I was to use CardLayout, how would one go about doing the rest like the Add button, after choosing the fields the user wants, then pressing the button. How would you get that to then display the image corresponding to the type chosen along with holding the type and quantity in that label?